# has_and_belongs_to_many, avoiding dupes in the join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a pretty simple HABTM set of models

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end 

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_and_belongs_to_many :tags

   def tags= (tag_list) 
      self.tags.clear 
      tag_list.strip.split(' ').each do 
        self.tags.build(:name => tag) 
      end
   end 
end
```

Now it all works alright except that I get a ton of duplicates in the Tags table.

What do I need to do to avoid duplicates (bases on name) in the tags table?

Comment: Do you mean duplicate in the join table (as title suggest) or tags table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked around this by creating a before_save filter that fixes stuff up.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
   before_save :fix_tags

   def tag_list= (tag_list) 
      self.tags.clear 
      tag_list.strip.split(' ').each do 
        self.tags.build(:name => tag) 
      end
   end  

    def fix_tags
      if self.tags.loaded?
        new_tags = [] 
        self.tags.each do |tag|
          if existing = Tag.find_by_name(tag.name) 
            new_tags << existing
          else 
            new_tags << tag
          end   
        end

        self.tags = new_tags 
      end
    end

end
```

It could be slightly optimised to work in batches with the tags, also it may need some slightly better transactional support.

Comment: This is exactly what the validates_uniqueness_of validator does. However, this solution alone doesn't prevent duplicate items because between your find_by_name and the association, an other request might write to the database. You can use this but you must be aware that some exceptions can occur (because you have an index) and you should catch them.

Comment: not really http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b6bac73b282c7e500c43810f2a937fc0047e5979/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations.rb it is a validation that will exception out if there is a dupe, it does not handle it transparently, it has documented concurrency issues, and does need to be used with a unique index to guarantee no dupes.

Comment: Yes, do it like this way and also add a unique index in the database. Then later on you can build on this model and add new data to it in case you need to store more information on each association.

Answer (score 73):

### Prevent duplicates *in the view only* (Lazy solution)

The following **does not** prevent writing duplicate relationships to the database, it only ensures `find` methods ignore duplicates.

**In Rails 5:**

```rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, -> { distinct }
```

*Note: `Relation#uniq` was depreciated in Rails 5 ([commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/adfab2dcf4003ca564d78d4425566dd2d9cd8b4f))*

**In Rails 4**

```rb
has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, -> { uniq }
```

---

### Prevent duplicate *data from being saved* (best solution)

**Option 1:** Prevent duplicates from the controller:

```
post.tags << tag unless post.tags.include?(tag)
```

However, multiple users could attempt `post.tags.include?(tag)` at the same time, thus this is subject to race conditions. This is discussed [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

For robustness you can also add this to the Post model (post.rb)

```
def tag=(tag)
  tags << tag unless tags.include?(tag)
end
```

**Option 2:** Create a unique index

The most foolproof way of *preventing duplicates* is to have duplicate constraints at the database layer. This can be achieved by adding a `unique index` on the table itself.

```
rails g migration add_index_to_posts
# migration file
add_index :posts_tags, [:post_id, :tag_id], :unique => true
add_index :posts_tags, :tag_id
```

Once you have the unique index, attempting to add a duplicate record will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` error. Handling this is out of the scope of this question. View [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694153/catch-all-exceptions-in-a-rails-controller).

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique, :with => :some_method
```

Comment: Best answer imho. You are doing something wrong in case you have dupes. Fix the problem with the unique index.

Comment: I wouldn't override any setters because such things most likely will give an extra pain in the ass to you or your peers. I'd create a separate method to add an associated object unless it was added before. In other words name `tag=` method something like `add_unique_tag`

Answer (score 25):

In addition the suggestions above:

1. add `:uniq` to the `has_and_belongs_to_many` association
2. adding unique index on the join table

I would do an explicit check to determine if the relationship already exists. For instance:

```
post = Post.find(1)
tag = Tag.find(2)
post.tags << tag unless post.tags.include?(tag)
```

Comment: Clean solution. In your `Post` model, add `def tag=(tag); tags << tag unless tags.include?(tag); end` for robustness.

Comment: Interestingly enough, [has_many association documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) (search for include?) recommends not using the `unless ...include?()` due to race conditions. I'm guessing the same could hold true for has_and_belongs_to_many.

Comment: Anyone got a confirmation for this?

Comment: any confirmation regarding this??

Comment: @Alfie I've used this in multiple projects in production and never experienced a problem. I've not seen the issue mentioned in has_many docs anywhere else. That's not conclusive however, just my own experience.

Comment: Thanks, but i changed to has_many through, since i had other purposes with the join table. So added a model and placed validations there.

Comment: @spyle If you add the recommended unique index on the joint table, then you will not get duplicates, but you should through an error in the (rare) race condition.

Comment: `include` is an Array method, it will load and loop over all the records in the relation, which not performant at all. Instead, use `tags.exists?(tag.id)`

Answer (score 20):

You can pass the `:uniq` option as [described in the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M002126). Also note that the `:uniq` options doesn't prevent the creation of duplicate relationships, it only ensures accessor/find methods will select them once.

If you want to prevent duplicates in the association table you should create an unique index and handle the exception. Also validates_uniqueness_of doesn't work as expected because you can fall into the case a second request is writing to the database between the time the first request checks for duplicates and writes into the database.

Comment: I tried that, it does not really solve the problem cleanly. I want to avoid exceptions in the first place. I think my solution kind of does that though it needs a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Note: I already had the unique constraint, which resulted in exceptions, handling them is a huge pain.

Comment: With the current version of will_paginate (3.0.3) having duplicates in the join table makes it impossible to have unique pagination.

Answer (score 20):

In Rails4:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, -> { uniq }
```

(beware, the `-> { uniq }` must be directly after the relation name, before other params)

[Rails documentation](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Comment: But `after_add` callback will be repeated every time again

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? Do you mean to say that `after_add` will still run even in the case that a record is not saved (thanks to {uniq})?

Comment: @nerith If I have another "has_and_belongs_to_many" in the other model referencing the first model, do you think I should set {uniq} there too?

Comment: No! This will still allow to write duplicates to the jointable, check answers above!

Comment: The `-> {uniq}` scope doesn't prevent duplicating data but helps displaying just one in the view.

Comment: Downvoted because this explicitly **does not avoid duplicates in the table**

Answer (score 12):

Set the uniq option:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_and_belongs_to_many :posts , :uniq => true
end 

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_and_belongs_to_many :tags , :uniq => true
```

Comment: This doesn't work as expected. You still get duplicate constraint errors when trying to add them via <<.

Comment: I just tried (on Rails 2.3.5), and this is not true. You should make your own question where you supply sufficient information to diagnose your issue.

Comment: I thought uniq ignores duplicates on reading but still allows you to write duplicates which would raise an db exception if you have duplicate constraint at the database layer

Comment: This won't prevent duplicates, it will just hide them from displaying

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer to adjust the model and create the classes this way:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :taggings
   has_many :posts, :through => :taggings
end 

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
   has_many :taggings
   has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
end

class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base 
   belongs_to :tag
   belongs_to :post
end
```

Then I would wrap the creation in logic so that Tag models were reused if it existed already.  I'd probably even put a unique constraint on the tag name to enforce it.  That makes it more efficient to search either way since you can just use the indexes on the join table (to find all posts for a particular tag, and all tags for a particular post).

The only catch is that you can't allow renaming of tags since changing the tag name would affect all uses of that tag.  Make the user delete the tag and create a new one instead.

Answer (score 3):

To me work

1. adding unique index on the join table
2. override << method in the relation

   ```
   has_and_belongs_to_many :groups do
     def << (group)
       group -= self if group.respond_to?(:to_a)
       super group unless include?(group)
     end
   end
   ```

Comment: Worked well for me along with the database constraint! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is really old but I thought I'd share my way of doing this.

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end 

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

In the code where I need to add tags to a post, I do something like:

```
new_tag = Tag.find_by(name: 'cool')
post.tag_ids = (post.tag_ids + [new_tag.id]).uniq
```

This has the effect of automatically adding/removing tags as necessary or doing nothing if that's the case.

Comment: Another way to express last line is `post.tag_ids |= [new_tag.id]` or `post.tags |= [new_tag]`, using [Array's set-like operators](http://www.virtuouscode.com/2012/08/27/array-set-operations-in-ruby/)

Answer (score 1):

Extract the tag name for security. Check whether or not the tag exists in your tags table, then create it if it doesn't:

```
name = params[:tag][:name]
@new_tag = Tag.where(name: name).first_or_create
```

Then check whether it exists within this specific collection, and push it if it doesn't:

```
@taggable.tags << @new_tag unless @taggable.tags.exists?(@new_tag)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an index on the tag :name property and then use the find_or_create method in the Tags#create method

[docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#find-or-create-by)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check in your controller before adding the record. If it does, do nothing, if it doesn't, add a new one:

```
u = current_user
a = @article
if u.articles.exists?(a)

else
  u.articles << a
end
```

More: "4.4.1.14 collection.exists?(...)"
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-and-belongs-to-many