# Hide Rails Errors in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i hide application errors in production mode and stop hem from showing to the users?

I want errors like this one not to show;

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer

5:   <%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>
6:   <%= f.input :password, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Password" %>
7:   <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label: false, placeholder: "Confirm Password" %>
8:   <%= f.input :submit , "Change Password" %>
9: <% end %>
10: 
11: <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you can define `rescue_from` statements in your application controller to rescue from exceptions and render error pages. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694153/catch-all-exceptions-in-a-rails-controller) gives an example.