# Rspec feature test issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

**spec/features/album_spec.rb:**

```
feature "Album Pages" do

  given(:album) { create(:album) } # by Factory_Girl

  scenario "Edit album" do
    visit edit_album_path album

    fill_in "Name", with: "bar"
    expect {click_button "Update Album"}.to change(Album.last, :name).to("bar")
  end

end
```

**error:**

```
  1) Album Pages Edit album
     Failure/Error: expect {click_button "Update Album"}.to change(Album.last, :name).to("bar")
       name should have been changed to "bar", but is now "Gorgeous Granite Table"
     # ./spec/features/albums_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

App works fine and if I click the button it redirects to album's site where its name is shown as `<h1>`. I tried this:

```
  scenario "Edit album" do
    visit edit_album_path album

    fill_in "Name", with: "bar"
    click_button "Update Album"
    save_and_open_page
    #expect {click_button "Update Album"}.to change(Album.last, :name).to("bar")
  end
```

than I got a page with that `bar` as `<h1>` so I don't know what's wrong with my test and I can see in the test.log:

```
SQL (0.7ms)  UPDATE "albums" SET "name" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "albums"."id" = 1  [["name", "bar"], ["updated_at", Fri, 11 Apr 2014 11:30:00 UTC +00:00]]
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I am assuming you have code somewhere on github that I can check out.

Comment: True, true: [here](https://github.com/pawel7318/footoo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your change validation to also be in block, like this:

```
scenario "Edit album" do
  visit edit_album_path album
  fill_in "Name", with: "bar"
  expect{click_button "Update Album"}.to change{Album.last.name}
end
```

Comment: It's working great ! Please read my own answer for this. I would appreciate some comments.

Answer (score 0):

After reading [drKreso's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185374/drkreso) answer I read `gems/rspec-expectations-.../lib/rspec/matchers.rb`. There are many usefull examples for `change` there.

> You can either pass receiver and message, or a block, but not both.

I find one other way how it can be done:

```
  scenario "Edit album" do

    @album = album
    visit edit_album_path @album    
    fill_in "Name", with: "bar"    

    expect{
      click_button "Update Album"
      @album.reload
      }.to change(@album, :name).to("bar")
  end
```

But even now I still have confusions why it didn't work on the first way. So if the `reload` is a key here than does `change` invoke it for passed receiver somewhere ? I wasn't able to go so deep.