# How to catch all exceptions in ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

How can we catch or/and handle all unhandled exceptions in ruby?

The motivation for this is maybe logging some kind of exceptions to different files or send and e-mail to the system administration, for example.

In Java we will do

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(UncaughtExceptionHandler ex);
```

In NodeJS

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function(error) {
   /*code*/
});
```

In PHP

```
register_shutdown_function('errorHandler');

function errorHandler() { 
    $error = error_get_last();
    /*code*/    
}
```

How can we do this with ruby?

Answer (score 11):

Advanced solution **use [exception_handler gem](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler)**

If you want just to catch all exceptions and put for example in your logs, you can add following code to `ApplicationController`:

```
begin
  # do something dodgy
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  # handle not found error
rescue ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError
  # handle other ActiveRecord errors
rescue # StandardError
  # handle most other errors
rescue Exception
  # handle everything else
end
```

More details you can find in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694153/catch-all-exceptions-in-a-rails-controller).

Comment: `rescue Exception` is really [heavy handed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby). You could mention why it's generally a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, I wasn't aware of that yet.

Comment: No problem. `rescue Exception` is like putting a snooze button on a fire alarm. You can do it, but you probably shouldn't ;)

Comment: Isn't ApplicationController part of Rails?

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby you would just wrap your program around a `begin` / `rescue` / `end` block. Any unhandled exception will bubble up to that block and be handled there.

Comment: Is this works even if we have an exception being thrown from another file or by a third party library?