# Deleting records from HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do something fairly simple. I have two models, User and Group. For simplicity's sake, let's say they look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :groups
end
```

and

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

Now, for some reason, I have a user that has the same group twice. In the Rails Console:

```
user = User.find(1000)

=> #<User id: 1000, first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", active: true, created_at:
"2013-01-02 16:52:36", updated_at: "2013-06-17 16:21:09">

groups = user.groups

=> [#<Group id: 1, name: "student", is_active: true, created_at: "2012-12-24 15:08:59",
updated_at: "2012-12-24 15:08:59">, #<Group id: 1, name: "student", is_active: true,
created_at: "2012-12-24 15:08:59", updated_at: "2012-12-24 15:08:59">]

user.groups = groups.uniq

=> [#<Group id: 1, name: "student", is_active: true, created_at: "2012-12-24 15:08:59",
updated_at: "2012-12-24 15:08:59">]

user.save

=> true
```

And there is some SQL output that I've silenced. I would think that everything should be all set, but it's not. The groups aren't updated, and that user still has both. I could go into the join table and manually remove the duplicates, but that seems cludgy and gross and unnecessary. What am I doing wrong here?

I'm running Rails 3.2.11 and Ruby 1.9.3p392

Additional note: I've tried this many different ways, including using user.update_attributes, and using group_ids instead of the groups themselves, to no avail.

Comment: That was a typo in posting this, in the console the variable name stayed consistent.

Comment: Thought I'd check the easy stuff first. ;-)

Comment: adding 'uniq: true' to the relation ships will help u to 'get' the uniq records but it wont stop form creating duplicates. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129781/has-and-belongs-to-many-avoiding-dupes-in-the-join-table

Comment: That's good to know, thank you. But is there any explanation as to why this doesn't work, and how I would make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because ActiveRecord isn't handling the invalid state of duplicates in the habtm association (or any `CollectionAssociation` for that matter).  Any `id`s not included in the newly assigned array are deleted - but there aren't any in this case.  The relevant code:

```
# From lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb

def replace_records(new_target, original_target)
  delete(target - new_target)
  unless concat(new_target - target)
    @target = original_target
    raise RecordNotSaved, "Failed to replace #{reflection.name} because one or more of the " \
                          "new records could not be saved."
  end
  target
end
```

The 'targets' being passed around are Arrays of assigned records.  Note the call to `delete(target - new_target)` is equivalent in your case to `delete(user.groups - user.groups.uniq)` which results in an empty Array passed (since comparison is based on the `id` attribute of each record).

Instead, you'll need to clear out the association and then reassign the single group again:

```
group = user.groups.first
user.groups.clear
user.groups << group
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a way to cleanup those duplicates (it handles any number of groups of duplicate associations):

```
user = User.find(1000)

user.groups << user.groups.group_by(&:id).values.find_all {|v| v.size > 1}.each {|duplicates| duplicates.uniq_by! {|obj| obj.id}}.flatten.each {|duplicate| user.groups.delete(duplicate)}
```