# How to use "-" on database relations in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have three relations, user, shopping_list and item. Users can have multiple shopping lists and shopping lists hold multiple items. The rule is that a shopping list can only hold one kind of item, like one "tv" for example.

On my webpage i have a spot where the user can select which shopping_list he/she would like to add the item too. The shopping lists appear in a drop down and the user selects it. It works fine but it does not follow the rule mentioned above. I would like to not show the shopping list if it already holds that item but continue to show the rest.

Here are my relations

```
create_table "shopping_lists", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "list_id"
    t.string  "name"
  end 


create_table "item", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "list_id"
    t.integer "item_id"
  end
```

How do i build my query so that when i am on a page i only get shopping lists that do not already hold that item?

(I thought about adding a user_id to the 'item' relation and then i could use the '-' operator, i'm not sure how that works in rails. do you think that would be the way to go?)

Comment: Do you have a field that holds the "type" of item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Validation**

There are two things to consider:

> 1. You could validate your way to unique fields
> 2. You could use indexes in your db

The first step is to ensure you're not populating your collection more than you want. You can do this either by [validating in the association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129781/has-and-belongs-to-many-avoiding-dupes-in-the-join-table):

```
#app/models/list.rb
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :items, uniq: true
end

#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :lists, uniq: true
end

#lists_items
list_id | item_id
```

or by using [indexes in you join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381154/rails-migration-for-has-and-belongs-to-many-join-table):

```
#migration
add_index(:lists_items, [:list_id, :item_id], :unique => true)
```

--

**Dropdown**

If you have a `select` box, you'll need to do something like the following (using [`.not`](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/activerecords-wherenot)):

```
collection_select(:item_ids, :item_id, Item.where.not("id IN (?)", current_user.list.map(&:item_id)), :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)
```

Not sure how you'll define the list `id`'s, but this is the foundation of what you need to do