# How to Deduplicate a HABTM join table in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a join table that joins students HABTM students

Unfortunately, it's gotten some duplicate records in it.

How can I deduplicate the join table. Ideally, using Ruby.

Comment: do you have a model for the join table or are you using the default Rails' `has_and_belongs_to_many` functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to delete duplicate records from HABTM table.

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE FROM TableName WHERE (model_id_one, model_id_two) IN (SELECT model_id_one model_id_two FROM TableName GROUP BY model_id_one, model_id_two HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)")

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help: [has_and_belongs_to_many, avoiding dupes in the join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129781/has-and-belongs-to-many-avoiding-dupes-in-the-join-table)

For showing related entries without duplicates:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :students, -> { distinct }
```

But also I recommend to add unique index on your join table.

Comment: no this isn't right, they are measures to only show unique items, not dedupe the db and the second one prevents the duplicates, which is the next task, that I can't do until it's de-duped.