# Ruby on Rails automatic bidirectional relationships not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I can't seem to get bidirectionality working on my Rails models. For example, in the rails console, when I execute the following:

```
r = Role.new
u = User.new
r.users << u
r.users
u.roles
```

The rails console states that role has users, but the user has no roles. If I save the role, then pull the user from the db, it has a role like it should, but the role's state doesn't stay consistent between the two objects.

I only have one db migration. Here is the code related to the two models (excluding simple data fields)

```
create_table :users do |t|
end

create_table :roles do |t|
end
    
create_join_table :users, :roles
```

Database itself also looks normal. Here are the two models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  # unrelated
  has_many :committee_enrollments
  has_many :committees, through: :committee_enrollments
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  # unrelated
  has_and_belongs_to_many :committees
end
```

All my associations are doing this. I can only get relations being set automatically when I specify inverse_of:. However, specifying source: doesn't work for through: relations.

ruby 2.7.1p83, Rails 6.1.3, postgresql 12.5, Ubuntu WSL

Edit: ok so I understand the relationship won't exist until I save. However, I am still having an issue with data inconsistency. For example:

```
r = Role.first
r2 = r.users.first.roles.first
r.role_name == r2.role_name
 => true
r.role_name = "changed"
r.role_name == r2.role_name
 => false
```

according to the [documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations), this second one should be true.

Comment: Did you save the role and user? `r.save u.save`.

Comment: *"If I save the role, then pull the user from the db, it has a role like it should"* --- Isn't this the only thing that matters? If you retrieve/reload a record, then it will refresh the state of its newly altered associations.

Comment: I thought that when I make two objects and set one association to another, it should also set the reverse automatically? It works that way for belongs_to relationships.

Comment: Ok so it doesn't set the reverse automatically in this case I guess. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

The association is not being saved and not even validated, you are just working with temporal data on your memory. If you save your records, you will be able to see their associations bidirectionaly.

```rb
u = User.create(YOUR_USER_MODEL_PARAMS)
r = Role.create(YOUR_ROLE_MODEL_PARAMS)
u.roles << r  # This will do the same than r.users << u
```

Also, with your database schema, associating records on that way allows duplicated associations (ex: one User with role 'admin' twice, you will watch this in action if you push twice the same association). In the long run, you're going to have a lot of duplicated records, you have two typical ways to avoid it:

**Option 1:** assign the associations using one of this ways

```rb
u.update(roles: [r]) # Array of roles
u.update(roles: Role.all)
u.roles = [r] # Array of roles
u.roles = Role.all # ActiveRecord::Relation
```

**Option 2:** prevent duplicated records on your Users-Roles join table by adding a unique index like Jeremy Lynch explains in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39328693/4168348) answer

```rb
rails g migration add_index_to_users_roles
# migration file
add_index :users_roles, [:user_id, :role_id], :unique => true
add_index :users_roles, :user_id
```

> Once you have the unique index, attempting to add a duplicate record will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique error. Handling this is out of the scope of this question. View [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694153/rails-catch-all-exceptions-in-a-rails-controller).

```rb
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique, :with => :some_method
```

Comment: Ok so in your example, I can't do r.users and have correct information until after I save u. Got it. Still having an issue with some inconsistent states, see my edit.
Also, thanks for the note about unique records. Great idea.

Comment: The problem is caused by the same reason, you are changing the value of a variable without persisting it in the database. The documentation you describe is for one-to-one and one-to-many relations, but does not mention that it works with many-to-many (`has_and_belongs_to`) relations hehe. With many to many relations things are pretty different because you have an intermediary table, not just one foreign key